# Material UI Grid item pushed upward due to image loading

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

When I am using the Material UI grid system with a project I am doing using create-react-app. I have two grid items that are adjacent to each other. That look like so:

[image]

This is exactly what I want.  For some reason; however, when the page loads for a split second the text on the right side gets pushed upward and flashes unstyled like so:[image]
I suspect it is because the image hasn't fully loaded, so the text sits higher up until the image loads.  Any advice on how to prevent this or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!

here is a code sandbox to recreate https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-jang-kbbty?file=/src/pages/Home.js

if you go from the home page to /portfolio when the code sandbox is in full screen, you will see the flash of unstyled content i am talking about.

```
      <Grid container justify='center' alignItems='center'>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={9} md={9} lg={6} xl={6}>
          <img src={JobTracker} alt='jobtracker' style={{ width: '100%' }} />
        </Grid>

        <Grid item xs={12} sm={9} md={9} lg={6} xl={6}>
          <Container maxWidth='xs'>
            <Typography variant='h3' style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
              JobTracker
            </Typography>
            <br />
            <Typography variant='body2'>
              A platform that allows recent graduates from Wyncode Academy to
              track job applications. Technologies used: ReactJS, NodeJS, Google
              Cloud Functions, and Google Firestore.
            </Typography>
         </Container>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
```

Comment: `I suspect it is because the image hasn't fully loaded` yup. Spot on. to fix it you would need to know the size of the images and change your css to fit it.

Comment: Would I need to create a series of media queries that layout the sizing of my image for each screen size?

Comment: Honestly I don't have that expertise, someone will chime in with it. But I would ask - If it's only a few ms, does it matter ? - EDIT: For brevity and clarity it is a common action to resize your images to particular resolutions, you can then feed those lower res ones into bad connections and buffer the better ones later. It's not my area though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, I usually wrap images in a wrapper has fixed ratio (usually golden ratio for me) to prevent this behavior. This is because, as long as image has not been loaded, the image container (in your case is `Grid` component) has zero height.

If you use fixed ratio wrapper approach, the image wrapper always have a height. That's it.
You can read more about that technique here: https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/

Comment: do you by chance have an example of how you used the wrapper? if not no worries just curious

Comment: This is an example for responsive square image container:

https://github.com/shinaBR2/devchallenges-portfolio/blob/master/src/components/Avatar/Avatar.js